# Truth table verification 10

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

The question:

Let $P$, $Q$, and $R$ be statements. Determine whether or not the two expressions in each pair are logically equivalent. In each case, demonstrate that your answer is correct.

a.) $(P ∧Q) ∧R, P ∧(Q ∧R)$

My attempt using truth table:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
P& Q & P ∧ Q& R \\ \hline
 T& T& T&T\\ \hline
 F& T & F&F\\ \hline
 T& F & F&F\\ \hline
F& F & F&F\\ \hline
\end{array}

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Q& R & Q ∧ R& P \\ \hline
 T& T& T&T\\ \hline
 F& T & F&F\\ \hline
 T& F & F&F\\ \hline
F& F & F&F\\ \hline
\end{array}

Therefore, they are equivelent.

Is this the correct method/approach to showing that the statements are correct using truth tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct. Although, you might use the fact that $\land$ is associative unless the problem specifically doesn't want you to do that. If that is the case, then the truth table is the only way.

Comment: Thank you, yes the professor had said to use truth tables.

Comment: @Forextrader Just to make the answer more complete, add one more column in the end for both tables, that includes the full expressions.

Comment: Ah that's a good thought. Thank you